# MapKit GeodesicPolyline zoom to show route

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I have an issue with zooming a map to show the entire route of a geodesic polyline that is drawn on my map.
Below is the code and also the protocol stub for makeUIView.

Essentially the route is showing fine but the map doesn't automatically in or out to show the route. I have the location region at the centre of the route

```
func addRoute(latitudeStart: Double, longitudeStart: Double, latitudeEnd: Double, longitudeEnd: Double) {
 
    var coordinates = [c1.coordinate, c2.coordinate]

    let c1 = CLLocation(latitude: latitudeStart, longitude: longitudeStart)
    let c2 = CLLocation(latitude: latitudeEnd, longitude: longitudeEnd)
    
    let zoom = c1.distance(from: c2)

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (latitudeStart+latitudeEnd) * 0.5, 
        longitude: (longitudeStart+longitudeEnd) * 0.5)
   
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, latitudinalMeters: zoom, 
        longitudinalMeters: zoom)
    
    //Draws a MKGeodesicPolyline between the two points.
    
    
    let geodesicPolyline = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: 2)

    mapView.addOverlay(geodesicPolyline)

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    
    mapView.setVisibleMapRect(geodesicPolyline.boundingMapRect, edgePadding: 
        UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0), animated: false)
    
}
```

And the Protocol Stub

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
let  region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.9424955, 
    longitude: -118.4080684), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 60.0, longitudeDelta: 
    60.0))

let adjustRegion = mapView.regionThatFits(region)

//mapView.region = region
mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
mapView.setRegion(adjustRegion, animated: true)

return mapView
```

}

Comment: Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: I've noticed it works over shorter distance but anything beyond say 4000miles it stops zooming